# html make a custom gmail inbox with no servers

Tags: php, html, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am making a dashboard and i need a Gmail inbox to be able to view my inbox from a page in my website or a like have an iframe or embed?

Please let me know if this is possible, thanks.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question, I feel that's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Vladan I just want an HTML embed an iframe of a Gmail inbox so I can see new emails that I receive

Comment: first of all, you need to register your application, second, having access to Gmail inbox is under restricted permissions, meaning you can't obtain access easily, [have a look](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

Due to different security reasons, you cannot create an `iframe` in a website where you place your Gmail inbox. What you can actually do instead is to use [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) to get all the main messages you are interested in your inbox and display them as you want in your website.

To achieve this you can use the method [users.messages:list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) to list the messages of your mailbox. You can filter them as you want by labels or maximum number of results for example and then use the response to generate HTML components with the contents of these messages.

If you are not familiar with Gmail API, here is a [Quickstart guide for PHP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) beginners that will guide you through it and help you implement the required authorization requirements with [oAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to do it using Gmail API

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

You can also lower your Gmail security setting to enable access from your code such as from php but it's not recommended.

So I would research other api or websites that would allow Gmail access

Comment: how do i do it thoughn how do i get it in my html?

Comment: You would have to write some php code to connect to gmail and get gmail data. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFQxTB0awiU.